# Eclipse issue with F3, F4 keys in Windows 8

Tags: eclipse, windows

In Eclipse, I must use <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to 'Open Declaration' for a method. By default, <kbd>F3</kbd> is the function key to adjust the monitor brightness. How can I reverse its functionality, in order to use <kbd>F3</kbd> for the 'Open Declaration' and <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> for the monitor brightness?

Comment: Are you sure that your keyboard doesn't actually have those reversed itself, requiring you to use a Fn to actually use F3 itself, in which case, you're looking for its Fn Lock?

Comment: Of course. I take so much more time to debug and do other functions in Eclipse. But I think this is more to do with my HP Pavilion machine with Windows 8, than Eclipse.

Comment: What brand of PC/Laptop are you using?

Comment: HP Pavilion PC with Windows8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution from [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-do-I-lock-and-unclock-the-FN-key/td-p/45847).

1. Boot into the bios using <kbd>F10</kbd> key on startup that is used on most HP laptops
2. Select the option system configuration in the BIOS screen.
3. Under system configuration you will find something as `action mode keys`, make it enabled then save the changes and then exit the BIOS screen.
4. Then you'll be able to `Open Declaration` using <kbd>F3</kbd> instead of <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: Got it resolved. Official link from HP support http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108